# How can I remove a docments in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

How can I remove a docments in Meteor.I get this error

> "Uncaught Error: Not permitted. Untrusted code may only remove
>   documents by ID. [403]"

list.js

```
 Template.KullaniciListele.events({
    'click #delete': function (id, template) {
     Meteor.users.remove({_id:id});
    }
  });
```

users.html

```
{{#each kullaniciList}}
  <tr>
   <td><a href="javascript:;" id="delete" >delete</a>
  </tr>
 {/each}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Event callbacks](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/eventmaps) take an `event` object as their first parameter. So your code is doing this:

```
Meteor.users.remove({_id: event});
```

Because `event` isn't a string, you're getting an error. Assuming each item in `kullaniciList` contains an `_id` (are they users?), then your code could look like:

```
Template.KullaniciListele.events({
  'click .delete': function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    Meteor.users.remove(this._id);
  }
});
```

Note that you can only have one `#delete` id on a page so I switched that to a class. The corresponding line in your template should be:

```
   <td><a href="#" class="delete">delete</a></td>
```

Note you were also missing the closing `</td>`.

---

If you have removed the `insecure` package, you will need to either add an [allow rule](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/allow) or write a [method](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_methods) for the user removal to actually succeed. Just to see something work, you could do this:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.users.allow({
    remove: function(userId, doc) {
      // JUST FOR TESTING - NEVER DO THIS IN PRODUCTION
      return true;
    }
  });
}
```

**WARNING!!** this is just to get something working - please don't add this to production code, as it allows any user to remove any other user. To do this right, you'll want to make sure the caller is an admin or something, but that's beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: I applied your code but i get this error "remove failed: Access denied. No allow validators set on restricted collection for method 'remove'."

Comment: You need an allow rule or a method. See the updated answer.